# Elasticsearch inverted search

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to query data from elasticsearch similar to this:

```
Select * From tbl where field not in (...)
```

Is there a way to add not in type logic to the elasticsearch query below?

```
GET /index/type/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "FIELD": "TEXT"
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use boolQuery and within bool query use mustNot

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must_not": [
           {
              "match": {
                 "FIELD": "TEXT"
              }
           }
        ]
    }
}
}
```

Comment: And filters whenever possible if you have a structured search and don't care about scoring. Bool filter would do it, same syntax as bool query.

Comment: another follow up question. "FIELD":"TEXT"  if the test is something like "AA-1234", elastic search doesn't search it. is there any special escape characters needed for something like this.

Comment: Es split the to text on non alphabetical character. So mention field to be not analyzed or create a custom analyser..  It will work..